# PresentViewController dismiss doesn`t go back to previous viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

On my project we have three windows A, B and C. From A I would like to push view B, and from B I would like to present view C.
My code:
ViewController A:

```
ViewControllerB *vcB = [[viewControllerB alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:vcB animated:YES];
```

View Controller B:

```
ViewControllerC *vcC = [[ViewControllerC alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerC" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:vcC animated: true completion: nil];
```

Everything is ok until now, but when I dismiss the last view controller with:

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

The app goes back to first view controller (vcA) instead the second one (vcB)

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you, guys.

Comment: Your first step should be renaming the view controllers to something significant. A, B, and C are super hard to follow and will cause confusion.

Comment: @Gabriel are you using UINavigationContoller properly, If yes, then share more detail about then so I can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be doing something else that you're not telling us about...

This works as expected:

In `MyFirstViewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)pushTapped:(id)sender {
    MyPushedViewController *vc = [[MyPushedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyPushedViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

In `MyPushedViewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)presentTapped:(id)sender {
    MyPresentedViewController *vc = [[MyPresentedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyPresentedViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In `MyPresentedViewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)dismissTapped:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Tapping the "dismiss" button in `MyPresentedViewController` dismisses the presented view controller (your `vcC`), leaving me at `MyPushedViewController` (your `vcB`) ... ***NOT*** at `MyFirstViewController` (your `vcA`).

Answer (score 0):

try this to dismiss vc

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]
```

and use this to pop

```
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: Do not work...
Apparently self.navigationController is nil

Answer (score 0):

[self presentingViewController] = Bvc , so here you actually dismissing B not C

```
 [Bvc dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

but   self = Cvc so here you dismissing C only

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```